# Hive decryption after DB2 encryption

Tags: encryption, hive, db2

```
select hex(encrypt('column', 'key')) from table

select aes_decrypt(unhex('column'), 'key') from Hive
```

I am inserting the dataset obtained through the sql statement into hive, and I am trying to decrypt the encrypted column in hive, but a null value is being returned.

What do you need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. There is no single "encrypt" and "decrypt" in the world, but many algorithms with variations of input. Have you checked that the above encrypt and aes_decrypt are compatible...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Db2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-encrypt)

> The internal encryption algorithm is RC2 block cipher with padding

so it's highly unlikely that you can successfully decrypt it using `aes_decrypt()`. Consider using the same algorithm to encrypt and decrypt your data.